# Can I read files /directories directly from MS teams to jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, microsoft-teams

I am working on a project where my client posting data(excel files) directly in MS teams Files section. And every time she updates any folder, I am again downloading that folder in my local system to work on it.

So if today I downloaded that particular folder and if she updates it tomorrow with more excel files, I am supposed to again download that folder or new files to my local system again, which is not good at all. Sometimes I am unable to trace the updates hence missing the updated files.

So is there any way by which I can directly read that MS teams file section directly in my jupyter notebook instead of downloading files in my local system and then reading files from local machine.

Till now I am reading files like this from my local:

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\project opportunity\Part1\AI\Input Design Work\Core Design.xlsm"
                      ,sheet_name="Allowance Plans"
                      ,skiprows=9)
```

Comment: Please go through these documentation. [Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from comments section for more visibility.

Please go through these documentation. [Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).